# Changing Shape Color in Visio

Tags: shapes, visio, color-coding

Need some help!

I'm relatively knowledgeable when it comes to macros, VBA, scripts, etc., but Visio coding is an all new monster to me.

In short, I have a warehouse map layout with simple square shapes marking product locations, and I want to color-code the squares based on their *Prop._VisDM_F2* data element. My code so far seems to work, but only for the 1st shape in the group of squares, but sometimes the master shape consists of 1 square, sometimes 6, and everything in between.

I've learned that the # in "Shapes(**#**)" selects which square gets changed, but I want them *ALL* to change. I've tried to get a count of how many individual shapes are in each master shape to use a variable integer as the **#**, but it didn't work.

Surely such a simple task can't really this complicated so I'm probably just missing something a step. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

'''

```
Dim selectObj As Visio.Shape

For Each selectObj In ActiveWindow.Selection
If selectObj.CellExistsU("Prop._VisDM_F2", Visio.VisExistsFlags.visExistsAnywhere) Then
selectObj.Shapes(1).Cells("Fillforegnd").FormulaU = visWhite
End If
Next

End Sub
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Shapes can have sub-shapes which are accessed through the Shapes property as per your code (note that most Visio collections are 1 rather than 0 based).

You can address the sub-shapes collection either by index or with a further for each.  So given that you may or may not know the depth of your sub-shapes you can recurse through them something like this:

```
Sub ApplyFillToAll()

Dim shp As Visio.Shape

For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection
    If shp.CellExistsU("Prop._VisDM_F2", Visio.VisExistsFlags.visExistsAnywhere) Then
        SetFill shp, "RGB(255,0,0)"
    End If
Next

End Sub

Public Sub SetFill(ByRef shpIn As Visio.Shape, fillFormula As String)

Dim shp As Visio.Shape

For Each shp In shpIn.Shapes
    shp.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaU = fillFormula
    SetFill shp, fillFormula
Next

End Sub
```

Note that the formula that you're setting is a string and so is wrapped in double quotes, and the above will set all of the sub-shapes to red with the SetFill method calling itself to navigate down through the tree.

I'll add a link to a very old post that you might also find useful:

https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2007/11/looping-through.html

Comment: Great.  Glad that's worked for you.  If you could mark the answer as accepted that would be very helpful.